# Check for the existence of custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, and I want to do a query to show all posts where a "date" field is before today and where another custom field (a report) has a value.

For now I have this, but I am always getting all past events.

```
       'post_type' => 'activiteit',
   'meta_key' => 'activiteit_datum',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array( 'key' => 'activiteit_verslag','compare'=>'EXISTS'),
      array( 'key' => 'activiteit_datum', 'compare' => '<', 'value' => $fullDate,'type' => 'DATE')

   )
);

$pastActivities=query_posts($arg);
```

Comment: There is a spurious single quote before "EXISTS". Is that in your code or is it a typo here only? Also, what format is your dates saved as and what is the format of `$fullDate`?

Comment: The single quote is a typo. Thanks for pointing me out. The date is saved in YYMMDD. The date filtering is working fine, but I get all past events back even when the field 'activiteit_verslag' is not filled in

Comment: Do you mean `YYYYMMDD`? Otherwise I am surprised the filtering works.

Comment: Yes I mean YYYYYYMMDD, sorry for that

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but might this just be a difference between key EXISTS and empty value?

Comment: I am having a hard time working out why this doesn't work. "EXIST" will return any post with that key present, even if the key value is empty or NULL (I believe this is what @ialocin is getting at). Could that be the problem?

Comment: So when the key value is not filled in, it rturns NULL. Can I change my query so that all fields that have the meta value null are excluded?

Comment: There seems to be a known and unresolved problem, see trac ticket 18158: [Meta Query for posts with a meta key not set (IS NULL).](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18158#comment:59) @s_ha_dum

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be, per the string of comments in the question, that the `activiteit_verslag` key is set for many, or all posts, even if the value is empty/`NULL`. `EXISTS` only checks the presence of the ***key***. The value is not considered, so too much is returned.

There are a couple of things I can see for you to do.

The first is to use `!=` instead of `EXISTS`.

```
array( 
  'key' => 'activiteit_verslag',
  'value' => '',
  'compare' => '!='
),
```

That should work but *only* if your values are consistently set to an empty string and *only* if the ***key*** is set for all posts.

`WP_Query`/`WP_Meta_Query` is not capable of complex logic like you would need to check whether the key is not set or set but empty, though you can write filters to make it work... but don't. The resulting SQL will become increasingly less efficient as the logic becomes more complicated.

The correct solution is to back up and alter how your data is saved. If you have an empty value for that `activiteit_verslag` key, then ***delete the key***. If you do that then your query above should work (obviously untested but I am pretty sure) and you will probably have the most efficient possible query for this circumstance.

I realize that you are using Advanced Custom Fields to do your work for you but @ialocin thinks the plugin may have filters that would let you alter its behavior.  I don't use ACF (or many other plugins because other people don't think like me and are therefore wrong :) ), so I don't know what you can or can't do with its hooks, but the Core hook `save_post` should do in a pinch.

Proof of concept:

```
add_action(
  'save_post',
  function($pid) {
    $empty = get_post_meta($pid,'delete_me',true);
    if (empty($empty)) {
      delete_post_meta($pid,'delete_me','');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Tkank you, I understand it. The problem is that I cannot alter the way my data is saved because I am using the advanced custom fields plugin. And when no activities_verslag is filled in, it returns null.

Maybe a solution (not the nicest one) is to do a query on past dates and then process the data with another custom loop

Comment: ACF can be customized easily, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/), especially ACF's own action and filter hooks. A good start would likely be the [acf/save_post](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/actions/acfsave_post/) hook. I'm pretty certain, that what s_ha_dum has suggested can be done with ACF in use. @MisterMelotte

Comment: @MisterMelotte : see the edit.

Comment: Of course you are right about not needing the plugin and ergo the plugin hook. But you know, not everyone can be as good as your are. BTW wouldn't this be like, why use wordpress, if you can do it on your own. ;) Besides that, I was suggesting the plugin hooks having in mind, that there possibly might be a way to prevent ACF saving empty fields in the first place, which would be nicer then saving and removing. One last addition, it might be necessary to give the function that removes the post meta a higher priority, just to make sure the sequence is always correct.

Comment: @ialocin : that "not thinking like me" part was a ___joke___ :) It is not worth doing everything yourself (though I do maintain that many plugins are far more trouble than they are worth). The first thing I said in the edit is that the plugin _might_ have hooks to alter its behavior, as you suggested. That is, _I am agreeing with you_. I don't have the time to dig through that massive plugin to work our how to actually do it though and offered a fallback solution if all else fails.

Comment: To be honest, we never disagreed. I might have missed the joke a little bit, but not totally, probably a language barrier problem. Besides that I just wanted to add a complementary comment. I guess I'm just too talkative today - this shall be the end of it. On the plus side, the question is covered really good now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I will give it a try later this evening or tomorrow If I find the time